# SharePoint 2013, ADFS, return URL

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, adfs

We have integrated our SharePoint environment with ADFS. Configured everything and we are able to authenticate using ADFS. However, after the successful login from the ADFS page, we are redirected to the root site instead of the requested URL.
below is the sample URL of the ADFS login page:

```
https://federation-sts.company.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://abcstg.company.com&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fabcstg.company.com%2fsites%2fsamplesite%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252Fsites%252Fsamplesite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue in past, it is due to some configuration steps missing.

- On ADFS side, when you " configure the url" during the relying party trust wizard...Make sure you added /_trust/ at the end of your web app url. Like https://url/_trust/
- Also Make Sure Realm Identifier Is Same On Both Side(SharePoint And Adfs).It Is Case Senstive.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end/amp/

Comment: ADFS has been configured and authentication is working properly. 

In our scenario: 

1. Requested the URL "https://abcstg.company.com/sites/samplesite" 
2. Select the ADFS provider as authentication
3. User will be redirected to the ADFS login page
4. Provider username and password, and additional multi-factor authentication
5. After successful authentication, instead of being redirected to the requested URL from step 1, we got redirected to the rootsite of the web application.
https://abcstg.company.com

Comment: What we want is to be redirected to the requested URL, not in the rootsite of the web application since we're adding users per sitecollection.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand...that's why I told u.make sure that you have put _trust word in your url when you run the wizard.if trust word is not there then it will redirect to root site....that was our issue in past

Comment: /_trust/ has been already added in the relying party url. what happens after the authentication is we are being redirected here:

- "https://abcstg.company.com/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=https%3A%2F%2Fabcstg%2Ecompany%2Ecom"

Accessing the URL: "https://abcstg.company.com/_trust/" leads us there as well.

Comment: im not certain if the relying party identifier should be in the format of urn:name:name, this is the last configuration we did and it now works.